# How can I toggle the multilevel numbering in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a report template in Word that the users need to be able to turn on and off the preset Heading numbering. (1., 1.1, 1.1.1 etc.) The report needs to be submitted differently, so a macro seems to be the answer.

Does anyone have any suggestion for a way to toggle the numbers?

Comment: Are the Heading styles being used for anything "special" in these reports, such as for generating TOCs, cross-references, etc.?

Comment: TOC, yes, but that will drop the numbering if they are turned off. I can update the TOC to deal with this.

Comment: You seem to be able to do it using List Galleries, but I can apply a list, but can't see how to clear the settings if I want to turn them off.

Comment: I asked about the TOC because, as I see it, there are two possible ways to approach this: assigning different styles (leaving numbering linked to one set of styles) or actually changing the number formatting (list template) associated with the styles. The former is certainly simpler than the latter - list templates are tricky things to deal with. If the TOC is the only thing associated with the Heading styles (no page numbering, StyleRef fields, etc.) then I'd try the former. A TOC level can be "linked" to more than one style, so that TOC should pick up both sets.